# selinux not working under containerd with selinux-enable=true

Tags: kubernetes, selinux, containerd

I have two k8s cluster, one using docker and another using containerd directly, both with selinux enabled.
but I found selinux not actually working on the containerd one, although this two cluster have the same version of containerd and runc.

did i miss some setting with containerd?

docker: file label is **container_file_t**, and process runs as **container_t**, selinux works fine

```
K8s version: 1.17
Docker version: 19.03.6
Containerd version: 1.2.10
selinux enable by adding ["selinux-enabled": true] to /etc/docker/daemon.json

// create pod using tomcat official image then check the process and file label
# kubectl exec tomcat -it -- ps -eZ
LABEL                             PID TTY          TIME CMD
system_u:system_r:container_t:s0:c655,c743          1 ?        00:00:00 java

# ls -Z /usr/local/openjdk-8/bin/java
system_u:object_r:container_file_t:s0:c655,c743 /usr/local/openjdk-8/bin/java
```

containerd: file label is **container_var_lib_t**, and process runs as **spc_t**, selinux makes no sense

```
K8s version: 1.15
Containerd version: 1.2.10
selinux enable by setting [enable_selinux = true] in /etc/containerd/config.toml

// create pod using tomcat official image then check the process and file label
# kubectl exec tomcat -it -- ps -eZ
LABEL                             PID TTY          TIME CMD
system_u:system_r:spc_t:s0          1 ?        00:00:00 java

# ls -Z /usr/local/openjdk-8/bin/java
system_u:object_r:container_var_lib_t:s0 /usr/local/openjdk-8/bin/java

// seems run as spc_t is correct
# sesearch -T -t container_var_lib_t | grep spc_t
   type_transition container_runtime_t container_var_lib_t : process spc_t;
```

Answer (score 1):

From this [issue](https://github.com/containerd/cri/issues/1195) we can read:

> Containerd includes minimal support for SELinux. More accurately, it
>   contains support to run ON systems using SELinux, but it does not make
>   use of SELinux to improve container security.
>
> All containers run with the 
>   `system_u:system_r:container_runtime_t:s0`  label, but no further
>   segmentation is made

There is no full support for what you are doing using Containerd. Your approach is correct but the problem is lack of support to this functionality.